# NSInvalidArgumentException in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I'm making a simple calculator and when I use the addition button, the iOS Simulator crashes and I get an NSInvalidArgumentException. What do I do to prevent this from happening?
Error Report:

```
2013-06-23 17:18:54.574 Tutorial Test (Storyboard)[9744:c07] -[ViewController2 addition]:     
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75858f0
2013-06-23 17:18:54.577 Tutorial Test (Storyboard)[9744:c07] *** Terminating app due to 
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController2 addition]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75858f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x1d1c4bd 0x1c80bbc 0x1c8094e 0x10e2705 0x162c0 0x16258 0xd7021     
0xd757f 0xd66e8 0x45cef 0x45f02 0x23d4a 0x15698 0x1becdf9 0x1becad0 0x1c06bf5 0x1c06962 
0x1c37bb6 0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b 0x1beb7e3 0x1beb668 0x12ffc 0x1e2d 0x1d55)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Code in ViewController that has this error:

View Controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//Calculator
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}

-(IBAction)addition;
-(IBAction)subtract;
-(IBAction)multiply;
-(IBAction)divide;
-(IBAction)clear;

@end
```

View Controller.m

```
//Addition
-(IBAction)plus
{
float a = ([textField1.text floatValue]);
float b = a+([textField2.text floatValue]);
label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", b];
}
```

Comment: Your interface specifies an `addition` method but your implementation shows `plus`. Are you sure you actually implemented `addition`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode. Buggy code's buggy, no matter what the IDE is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named the method in the `.m` file `plus`, rather than `addition`. That is why the method `addition` isn't found, and the fix would be to rename the method in the `.m` file from `plus` to `addition`:

```
//Addition
-(IBAction)addition
{
    float a = [textField1.text floatValue];
    float b = [textField2.text floatValue];
    label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", a+b];
}
```

Comment: Minor suggestion - set `b` to just the value of the 2nd text field. Then add `a + b`. This makes it easier to debug and see the separate values.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't inplement the right method.

You call `addition` but you never actually implement it. Declaring the method signature in the .h is not enough, you have to code the method.

Comment: that is not true. they can go both in the .m and the .h

Comment: I don't use IB, but I'd imagine if anything the interface should be marked `IBAction`, not the implementation.

Comment: Note sure why this is getting downvoted, since it's correct.  comrod hasn't implemented the `addition` method in his `ViewController2`.  That's why he's getting the error.

Comment: Every ib i have usedd (100+) has always gone in the .m

Comment: A method can be declared `IBAction` in either the `.h` or the `.m` (or both).  However, if it is declared in the `.h` at all, it must be declared `IBAction` there.  It cannot be declared `void` in the `.h` and then `IBAction` in the `.m`.  If it is declared `IBAction` in the `.h`, it can be declared either `IBAction` or `void` in the `.m`.

Comment: Ok. Good to know, always a learning day in stackoverflow. Thanks. But yes the method was never implemented...

Comment: @robmayoff The downvote(s) were for the original answer I believe. The answer was promptly updated within 5 minutes so the edit history doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you allocated an instance of the `ViewController2` class?

For example:

```
ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
[vc2 addition];
```

Also, if the .m code you posted is the full contents of that file, then you're also missing

```
-(IBAction)addition {
    ...
}
```

Comment: If there wasn't an allocated instance, that wouldn't be the error.

Answer (score -1):

This means that the selector that you are calling is not available on the class you called it against.  The best thing to do is place a breakpoint where the method is being called.  Go to the debugger and po your object.

```
po 0x75858f0
```

in this instance.  However that number could be an object and it could be different.  Look at the number in the console.

Make sure the object is of the proper class.  Then check that class to make sure it responds to the selector you are calling.

**Edit: Your problem is that your plus method should be renamed to addition.  The names in the .h must match the names in the .m**

Comment: You state that `ViewController2 doesn't have a **class method** for addition. You mean **instance method**.

Comment: @Inturbidus: look at the log: it says "-[ViewController2 addition]:     
unrecognized selector sent to instance...". Notice the MINUS: it means it's complaining about an instance method. For class method, it would be PLUS.